# Selenium Webdriver - trying to click "Change to English" link by xpath but doesnt work

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a very basic test to open google.com in any other language than English and then, on the result page, click on "Change to English" option.

**Inspection of that option (Change to English) in dev tool is:**

```
<a style="display:inline-block;line-height:18px;margin-top:8px;padding:0;font-size:13px" href="/setprefs?sig=0_u_O-c-n5Y1GoUndibKuy1e6a-oA%3D&amp;source=en_ignored_notification&amp;prev=https://www.google.com/search?source%3Dhp%26ei%3DEcYBX7StFonBlwSOy5qIBQ%26q%3Dwebdriver%26oq%3Dwebdriver%26gs_lcp%3DCgZwc3ktYWIQA1C1F1i1GGDDGGgAcAB4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo%26sclient%3Dpsy-ab%26ved%3D0ahUKEwj0-ZmEjbbqAhWJ4IUKHY6lBlEQ4dUDCAc%26uact%3D5&amp;hl=en&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwir8Y-0nrbqAhUG4YUKHU9zBUwQhoQCKAF6BAgNECg">Change to English</a>
```

**My code is:**

```
(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
  try {
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/');

    await driver.manage().window().maximize();

    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    (await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="Rzn5id"]/div/a[2]'))).click;

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 10000);

  } finally {

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    await driver.quit();
  }

})();
```

But this code doesn't click on the link.

Any help please? Thanking in advance.

Comment: by the way, i added the xpath by right clicking the dev tool inspection and copy > copy xpath.

Comment: There is good chance that 'id' used in xpath may be dynamic and it may change every time. If your looking for xpath for html provided in question. Please try below xpath: `//a[text()='Change to English']`

Comment: Thanks @KuldeepKamune. I can find the element (as i logged it in console) but it is not clicking on that found element.

Comment: looks like your using javascript. To click on element, it should be `click()`.

Comment: @KuldeepKamune thanks for pointing out. I corrected it.